# Registering global variable accessable from VIews in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want t expose images storage URL to views so I can use it like this in *all* my views:

```
<img ng-src="{{storageUrl}}/logo.png"
```

Right now I have config service which I inject in my every controller, and then expose `storageUrl` variable to view via `$scope`.

```
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'AppConfigService',
    function ($scope, AppConfigService) {
        $scope.storageUrl = AppConfigService.storageUrl;
    }
```

But the problem is that almost in every controller I need to inject this service and expose this varialbe to the view. I don't want to duplicate code so much. So i'm intersting in other ways to globally expose some config variable to the *ALL* views. What you can suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The "global" scope way

Set it on `$rootScope`. Although global scope is ill-advised.

Also, if you must use global scope ($rootScope) to track this, you can set it in a `run()` block, and it will be set as soon as the application is ready:

```
angular.module('myApp').run([
  '$rootScope', 'AppConfigService', 
  function($rootScope, AppConfigService) {
    $rootScope.storageUrl = AppConfigService.storageUrl
  }
]);
```

The problem with global scope is that any other modules you load into your app could easily clobber your variable on $rootScope and it will be very hard to debug.

### Better way: Use the service directly in an "outer controller":

```
app.controller('OuterCtrl', [
  '$scope', 'AppConfigService', 
  function($scope, AppConfigService) {
    $scope.config = AppConfigService;
  }
]);
```

Then wrap your whole app in that controller:

```
<body ng-controller="OuterCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> other stuff here </div>
</body>
```

Why does this work? Because all controllers and directives under this controller prototypically inherit their scope from this controller's scope.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a directive for this, and use that directive everywhere instead of `ng-src`. Something like this:

```
myModule.directive('mySrc', ['AppConfigService', function(AppConfigService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            element.attr('src', AppConfigService.storageUrl + attrs.mySrc);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then you can just use relative paths for your images everywhere

```
<img my-src="/logo.png" />
```